# Mean is not recognized as a internal command

Tags: mean.io

`npm install -g mean-cli` works. but `mean init` says mean is not recognized as a internal command. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed mean-cli from git, worked like a charm.

1. Open CMD
2. Run this: npm install -g git://github.com/djskinner/mean-cli.git

Hope this works for you too

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly a NPM cache issue. Try running the following:

Update NPM

```
npm update -g npm
```

Then clear your NPM cache

```
npm cache clean
```

Once both commands have successfully ran, continue with the init

```
mean init <yourAppName>
```

For more reference material be sure to check out the docs at [learn.mean.io](http://learn.mean.io/#mean-stack-installation-install-the-mean-cli).